# how to get Refresh token in google oauth 2.0 api with PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using to generate an access token and it's working successfully, as the access token is for a short time of 1 Hour, I want to get the Refresh Token of the user and store in DB so that I can get the access token anytime I need.

below is my code in two files.

file Oauth.php

```
 <?php 
 require  'vendor/autoload.php';
 // Refer to the PHP quickstart on how to setup the environment:

 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAccessType('offline');
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');  //file downloaded earlier
 $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
 $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
 header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); //redirect user to Google
```

2nd File get_token.php

```
 <?php 
require  'vendor/autoload.php';
// Refer to the PHP quickstart on how to setup the environment:
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
?>
```

Response I am getting like this https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/google_calendar/get_token.php?code=4/0AY0e-g7ZauFJQPlzm1KsNpeuTF8S_5alcpjX8TA9LN0GVJd2cD0gAAiDPU56j2C9sVKIfg&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 3):

I did this with the following

```
<?php 
require  '../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret_234rcontent.com.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
 '/google_calendar2/oauth2callback.php');
 // offline access will give you both an access and refresh token so that
 // your app can refresh the access token without user interaction.
 $client->setAccessType('offline');
 // Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.
// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

Redirect uri code

```
<?php
require  'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret_2344056t4.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
'/google_calendar2/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$credentials=$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
// $refresh_token = $credentials['refresh_token'];
print_r($credentials);
```

Comment: The `authenticate` is deprecated and the `getRefreshToken()` returns null when used after `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code'])`, can add to your answer how to get the refresh_token with the new function?

Comment: To answer my own comment: `$client->setPrompt('consent');` is **required** in order to get a refresh_token

Answer (score 0):

When you get the access token returned from Google, what is in the response body? A refresh token is supposed to be passed back within the initial response based on OAuth 2.0 standard, and you will need to store this token somewhere safe. When you need to refresh the access token, you will need to pass in this stored refresh token with the request (maybe within the query string as a parameter), and then Google will send you back the new access token. Read through Google Documentation thoroughly as this should be explained in details!
[image]
[image]
As you could see in the response I get from Google OAuth above, the second picture is the response you are supposed to get, repeat your process of requesting the access token, and see if you get the response like what I get in the picture, and you will notice the refresh_token in the response body.

Comment: S I am getting a response like this https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/google_calendar/get_token.php?code=4/0AY0e-g7ZauFJQPlzm1KsNpeuTF8S_5alcpjX8TA9LN0GVJd2cD0gAAiDPU56j2C9sVKIfg&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Comment: Can you post the response in an image or in code with JSON format? I can't read it the way you pasted it.

Comment: You could understand this, it's simple English. Please post the FULL response, thank you, the response is cut off at the end of the string in the screen shot