# how to get refresh token for login with google api?

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

First of all, i am an absolute beginner in google apis. I followed this tutorial along with many other tutorials on the web -> `https://www.webslesson.info/2019/09/how-to-make-login-with-google-account-using-php.html`
and it is successfully working. But i cant refresh the page after login because i dont have a refresh token.

My config.php-

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$google_client = new Google_Client();
$google_client->setClientId('client id here');
$google_client->setClientSecret('client screct here');
$google_client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/realestate/index.php');
$google_client->addScope('email');
$google_client->addScope('profile');

$google_client->setAccessType('offline');
$google_client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

?>
```

My index file-

```
<?php

//Include Configuration File
include('config.php');

$login_button = '';


if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{

$token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

if(!isset($token['error']))
{

$google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];

$google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);


$data = $google_service->userinfo->get();


    if(!empty($data['given_name']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $data['given_name'];
    }

    if(!empty($data['family_name']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $data['family_name'];
    }

    if(!empty($data['email']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $data['email'];
    }

        if(!empty($data['gender']))
        {
        $_SESSION['user_gender'] = $data['gender'];
        }

        if(!empty($data['picture']))
        {
            $_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['picture'];
        }
  

    }
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{

    $login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'">Login With Google</a>';
}

?>
```

I asked a question somewhat related to this question but that was not working. So I asked again here, sorry for that.

***So,how can i setup refresh token ?***

Answer (score 3):

You actually do have a refresh token. THe issue or rather google thinks you do.

When you add this to your code

```
$google_client->setAccessType('offline');
```

It tells google that you would like to access the users data when the user is not online.
However the problem you are having is that with some languages the PHP for example, Google sends the refresh token to you the first time the user authenticates and then they assume that you have stored it on your server someplace so that you can use it the next time.  If you log the user in again you often will not be granted a new refresh token because again they think you have one.

How to fix this is to have the user revoke your access [revoke](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions).  Then the next time they visit your site they should be prompted to login this time you should have a refresh token.  Remember to store it someplace so that you have it next time.

Also when you refresh the access token remember to check that the refresh token is there and if its different then the one you have then store the new one

```
// Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
```

## Update for the frustrated. user447951

If you are not seeing a refresh token even after adding offline it is because this client library does not return to you a refresh token after every call, authorization request or refresh of the access token.  (yes some of the google client libraries do, this one does not)

It doesn't because It is assumed when the user authorized the application the first time that the developer stored it, so the next time you authorize the user you will not get a new refresh token back.  Nor will you get one when you refresh the access token.

You need to go to either the users google account and revoke access for the third party app then request authorizing of the user again.  or use the revoke endpoint to revoke the users access.  When the user is prompted again to request authorizing then a new refresh token will be returned.  This time save it.

NO it is not enough to just remove the credentials that you have stored in your system and use force prompt.  There must be nothing in the users account to state they had previously granted this application access.

1. use the revoke end point to revoke the users access to the app
2. Go to the users account under third party pass with access and revoke it.

Comment: when  i use the above code to get refresh token , i get this error- >Notice: Undefined index: expires_in  and this -> Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set the stored refresh token into the $client

Comment: Invalid grant error is very hard to debug it can have at least ten different causes that i know of. https://youtu.be/PKrOPS_8ze0

Comment: anyway how can i store the refresh token  like you said  with related to the if() block above?

Comment: thats what file_put_contents does i store it in a file for the user.  Have you checked the full sample i gave you in your other question? https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%20People%20API/v1

Comment: This lead me to the right direction, what finally solved it was `$client->setPrompt('consent');` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214805/1682509

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling this in your code:

```
$token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);
```

you are getting refresh token too in `$token['refresh_token']`;
save this refresh token on your end and use it like

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($token['refresh_token']);
```